# Use plain text field without taxonomy to achieve tagging in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, tagging

Using node reference is too heavy and I don't want to use taxonomy. What I want is to to use text field. But I don't want user to type the text but choose from a list of options instead.

So this text field can get from somewhere its own data source like some tags, then user select the tag, then the text field will be filled with the tag text.

The data source would preferably be configured as a variable.

I couldn't find any module to accomplish this yet.

Comment: You can't find any module cause you need no-one to do this... juste create your custom Content type, and add a select box on it wich options you want... nothing more complicated.

Comment: I think you must be more explicit with what you mean with "too heavy". Why you think this will generate problems. It's not clear to me if its too heavy for saving the data, or to heavy for the user when choosing the data, of too heavy when viewing it... it's not clear I think.

Comment: Taxonomy is a term which is a reference id. That would involves association which means the data itself when being used involving more operations than plain text in my particular use case so I don't want to use it. So heavy is in terms of to development. Anyways, my goal is to use text. As @M.Be has pointed out rightly, I can implement something my own but still I would like to try my luck to search some wheels.